# Includes and GET

Tags: php

I currently have profiles on my website with a unordered list for the navigation, when a list item is clicked it loads the content from a AJAX call.

```
"Users Uploads" -> AJAX -> request.php with $_POST['id'] = '1' & $_POST['request'] = 'users_uploads' -> include_once('user_uploads.php');
```

now the problem with this is that i cannot pass the $_GET through to the user_uploads.php as it needs it to find the specific users uploads. I know this is a terrible way of handling the requests but i already have it set for the other tabs.

```
if($_POST['request'] == "photos"){$user->requestPhotos($_POST['id']);}
```

What would be a effiecent way of somehow passing the $_GET through to user_uploads.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason that user_uploads can't check $_GET directly? Otherwise, whatever's happening in that script could be encapsulated in a function, and you pass in the $_GET value as a parameter.

Or you copy $_GET to a global variable that the user_upload code checks for.

Comment: Well i have tried this
if($_POST['request'] == "activity"){include_once('user_uploads.php?id=2');}

but it returns

Warning: include_once(user_uploads.php?id=2) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream:

Comment: you can't use query parameters on a local file operation. Those don't go through the HTTP layer, so the OS is looking for a file whose literal name is `user_uploads.php?id=2`, which doesn't exist. You could use a full-blown HTTP://example.com/user_uploads.php type url, but that'd be a serious waste of resources to fetch a file that's already local.

Comment: I think my best bet is to redo my whole content retreival system. Thanks for your help.